# fetch и try..catch, почему не работает

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

Есть вот такая конструкция:

```
try {
   fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => callback(data));
} catch(e) {
   console.dir(e);
}
```

Когда намерено передаю неверный `url`, в консоль выводится не обработанное исключение.

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at <anonymous>:120:28`

Как обрабатывать исключения в данном случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => callback(data))
    .catch(() => {
        console.log('error')
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Так просто!